# How to change the font size when exporting a markdown file as pdf on VS Code? (Markdown PDF - yzane)

Tags: pdf, visual-studio-code, markdown

I have been using the Markdown PDF extension for almost 2 months now and been a big fan of it but I feel like the default font size is a bit big and I would like to edit that. I haven't played around with the default settings of any extension before so have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can add css files to change the style for the generator.

### First, create a css file

You need to create the css file. For example, at the root of the project: *markdown.css*.

The content I use:

```
p, li, ul, code {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:150%;
}
```

### Then, update the vscode project's settings

In the file *.vscode/settings.json*, add the lines:

```
"markdown-pdf.styles": [
    "markdown.css"
]
```

If the *settings.json*'s file is missing, you need to create it and do not forget the curly brackets :

```
{
    "markdown-pdf.styles": [
       "markdown.css"
    ] 
}
```

### To go further

*markdown-pdf.styles* is an option interpreted by the plugin ([the list of the existing options](https://github.com/yzane/vscode-markdown-pdf#options)). You can remove the default style with the option *markdown-pdf.includeDefaultStyles* set to *false*.

And if you want to adapt the css file to your needs, generate the markdown as an html file with the command: "*Markdown PDF: Export (html)*". And then, you can check the HTML tags.